# Casting $_POST to specific Int Javascript PHP

Tags: javascript, php, function, post, isset

I was wondering if someone could help me with a small problem - I am passing `$_POST` through to a new tab using Javascript from a input box upon clicking of the table row, the function will accept `$_POST['shift']` as `B`. However, my Shifts are in an array and therefore I wanted to cast them as ints. My attempt at checking the value of `$_POST` is coming up short, it will not populate the next pages input box with the correct intval - it defaults to 0. I have included my index check, the function and the var dump. Any help would be appreciated, maybe I am just being stupid.

```
if ( isset($_POST['shift'])) {
  $ShiftSelected =  intval($_POST['shift']);
} elseif ($_POST['shift'] == 'B') {
  $ShiftSelected = 1;
} else {
  $ShiftSelected = 0;
}

$(function() {
  $(".table-row").click(function() {
    $("#form").attr('action', '?action=HS');
    $("#selectDate").val($(this).data("date"));
    $("#selectShift").val($(this).data("shift"));
    $("#form").submit();
  }); 
});

array(4) {
  ["workcenter"]=> string(1) "0" 
  ["Week"]=> string(2) "38"
  ["date"]=> string(10) "16-09-2016"
  ["shift"]=>string(1) "B"
}
```

Comment: You could probably try using `chr()` and `ord()` in PHP - in your case you would more likely want to use `ord('B')` to get an integer value

Comment: worth mentioning, your `elseif($_POST['shift'] == 'B'){...}` is unreachable

Comment: It was clearly unreachable, too early in the morning. Have removed the intval as it is an inhouse application to display info for crews si injection isn't really a concern. For what it's worth i'll edit in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ShiftSelected = 0;

if (isset($_POST['shift'])) {
    if ($_POST['shift'] == 'B') {
        $ShiftSelected = 1;
    } elseif ($_POST['shift'] == 'A') {
        $ShiftSelected = 0;
    }
}
```